# Material ui multiple Select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

this is my code :
[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-nxzuy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

when I select an item from Select component; the value of

> event.target.value

is undefined !!

What is proper implementation?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to pass a value prop to `MenuItem`

Please refer below code

```
  <TextField
    classes={{ root: classes.root }}
    select
    name="userRoles"
    id="userRoles"
    variant="outlined"
    label="userRoles"
    SelectProps={{
      multiple: true,
      value: formState.userRoles,
      onChange: handleFieldChange
    }}
  >
    <MenuItem value="admin">Admin</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="user1">User1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="user2">User2</MenuItem>
  </TextField>
```

Please refer to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fm3jf) sandbox for example

Comment: How would I pass multiple values? Like a dimension set WxH? Besides a string '300x250'

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [documentation of Multiple Select in MUI](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select) you have to iterate over each option and check if it is `selected`.

```js
const handleChangeMultiple = event => {
    const { options } = event.target;
    const value = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i += 1) {
      if (options[i].selected) {
        value.push(options[i].value);
      }
    }
    console.log(value); // selected options
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass value for each option.

```
<MenuItem value="Admin">Admin</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value="User1">User1</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value="User2">User2</MenuItem>
```